# [AngularJS]Export excel with file exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, xlsx, alasql

I defined one file report include title, header,width for every cell.... i call this my template (picture 1).I have used the alasql lib for export the excel for my website.I received a file (picture 2). Now, I want export data to my template but i don't understand to do that.So,Is there any way to make it export to my template with data?

[Picture 1 : this is my template want export data to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPpMU.png)

[Picture 2: this is a file when my using alasql in my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptx7Z.png)

Comment: You can not update an existing file. What you can do is to have a file that you set up as to look into another excel thats the result of an export from AlaSQL

Comment: @mathiasrw Hi sir, so I want export data from web to excel,but  i would like the excel look the picture 1? Can I do that? Can give me an example?